# Mismatch in Columns in SQL Server tables that should have the same columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can we identify columns that are not in a table that should have the same columns as another table with a SQL Query?

For example, table Transactions should have the same columns as table Transactions_History. There can also be multiple History tables e.g. Transactions_History01, Transactions_History02 etc.

The problem is when columns are added to Transactions, it is not being added to the History tables.

Comment: How do you know which tables belong together?

Comment: The naming convention e.g. Transactions will have other tables that should have the same columns named Transactions_[Something]

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Trying to keep the columns in sync as it causes errors when someone adds a columns to the master table e.g. Transactions but not the other tables e.g. Transactions_History

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`, you could achieve this with something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT BaseTable = C1.TABLE_NAME, MatchedTable = C2.TABLE_NAME, MissingColumn = C1.COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS C1
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS C2
    ON C2.TABLE_NAME LIKE C1.TABLE_NAME + '[_]_%'
WHERE C1.TABLE_NAME = 'BaseTable'
AND NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C3
    WHERE C3.TABLE_NAME = C2.TABLE_NAME
    AND C3.COLUMN_NAME = C1.COLUMN_NAME
);
```

NOTE: If this isn't for a specific table, you could leave out the `WHERE C1.TABLE_NAME = 'BaseTable'` part and you should be able to see all unmatched columns for any table where the base table has a corresponding _something table.

EDIT: Here's how you could do the same thing with sys tables:

```
SELECT DISTINCT BaseTable = T1.Name, MatchedTable = T2.Name, MissingColumn = C1.Name
FROM sys.tables AS T1
JOIN sys.columns AS C1
    ON C1.[object_id] = T1.[object_id]
JOIN sys.tables AS T2
    ON T2.Name LIKE T1.Name + '[_]_%'
JOIN sys.columns AS C2
    ON C2.[object_id] = T2.[object_id]
WHERE T1.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID('MySchema.BaseTable')
AND NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM sys.tables AS T3
    JOIN sys.columns AS C3
        ON C3.[object_id] = T3.[object_id]
    WHERE T3.[object_id] = T2.[object_id]
    AND C3.Name = C1.Name
);
```

Comment: Thanks, I have been using sys.tables and sys.columns to identify the columns but the above query is not returning any results?

Comment: @SamoanProgrammer For querying a table, there should be no difference between using `sys` tables and `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views. Are you running these two queries in the same database? Regardless, I'll edit in an example of the same sort of thing using sys tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can query the information_schema views to identify and compare the columns of each paired table.

Comment: Hi, that's what I do currently but I was after a SQL Query that will just show me so I can create an ALTER Script from it to add in the Missing columns.